# How to filter displayed Products according to the its ProductType in TabControl- TabPages in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been following this tutorial on youtube and got stuck in this part of it.

Here I have to display products in my database dynamically on a TabControl Tab Pages according to product's type, but I can't seem to filter products according to the Tab page product types and all the products show up on every product type as below.

Please see screen shots below for the database and application and any help on this issue would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

**Code to display product types as tab pages**

```
private void CreateTabPages()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT ProductType, Description FROM TblProductType", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(dr["ProductType"].ToString(),dr["Description"].ToString());
            }

            //var tabID = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                         // select (Int32)dr["TabID"]).Distinct();
            con.Close();
```

**Updated code to display products**

```
private void AddProductsToTabbedPanel()
    {
        foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sdaProductType = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductType FROM TblProductType WHERE Description =" + tp.Text, con);
            DataTable dtForProductType = new DataTable();
            sdaProductType.Fill(dtForProductType);
            string currentProductType = (string)dtForProductType.Rows[0]["ProductType"];
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM TblProduct WHERE ProductType =" + currentProductType, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                b.Text = dr["Description"].ToString();
                flp.Controls.Add(b);
            }

            tp.Controls.Add(flp);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does: `SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM TblProducts WHERE Description IN ProductType = "+ i.ToString()` mean? this surely is a mistake. And were did you get the I from?

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake. I just edited the code in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the very risky approach of building dynamic SQL text in your app (do a web search for "SQL Injection"), your SQL for adding products to a tab is wrong.

Specifically, this line (line breaks added for readability):

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
    SELECT DISTINCT Description 
    FROM TblProducts 
    WHERE Description IN ProductType = " + i.ToString(), con);
```

What you probably wanted is:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
    SELECT DISTINCT Description 
    FROM TblProducts 
    WHERE ProductType = " + i.ToString(), con);
```

I have no idea where you are getting `i` from in this context, perhaps you should be reading some property of the current tab while you loop through them? A common hack used to be the `Tag` property.

**UPDATE**:

Try saving the Product Type when creating the tabs:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    var tabPage = new TabPage(dr["Description"].ToString());
    tabPage.Tag = dr["ProductType"].ToString();
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
}
```

Now you have access to the Product Type for the current tab, so in your loop where you populate each page:

```
foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    string productTypeID = (string)tp.Tag;
    // other code...
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
        SELECT DISTINCT Description 
        FROM TblProducts 
        WHERE ProductType = " + productTypeID, con);
    // rest of your code...
}
```

It feels a little dirty, but that's the way we did things in WinForms for years, putting custom data in the Tag property of controls.

Comment: I changed SQL statement as you told me. But still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are not filtering the query you are using in populating the tabPage.

What you need to do is first get which **ProductType** the current TabPage represent. Here I just added the query in the DB that filters the product by ProductType.

```
foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sdaProductType =  new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductType FROM TblProductType WHERE Description =\"" + tp.Text + "\"", con);
                DataTable dtForProductType = new DataTable();
                sdaProductType.Fill(dtForProductType);
                string currentProductType = dtForProductType.Rows[0]["ProductType"];
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM TblProducts WHERE ProductType =" + currentProductType, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
                flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Button b = new Button();
                    b.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                    b.Text = dr["Description"].ToString(); 
                    flp.Controls.Add(b);
                }

                tp.Controls.Add(flp);
                con.Close();
            }
```

The **currentProductType** is the ProductType the current TabPage represents. I used the **Text** property of the TabPage to retrieve the correct ProductType to use as a filter for the second query for populating the TabPage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: With few changes I tried this. But it now it gives me an error. "Incorrect syntax near 'Drinks'."

Comment: Anyway I decided to go forward with your method and updated the code with changes I made.

Comment: Forgot to enclose the tp.Text in double quotes. My bad! I would greatly appreciate an accept. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Change your ProductType Column data type to `int` so you can loop using the foreach statement over the data to view.

Here's the code.

```
 private void AddProductsToPannel()
    {
        int i = 1;
        foreach (TabPage tp in tabcon_ProductList.TabPages)
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM Tbl_Product Where ProductType =" + i, connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            FlowLayoutPanel flowLayout = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            flowLayout.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                b.Text = dr["Description"].ToString(); 
                flowLayout.Controls.Add(b);
            }

            tp.Controls.Add(flowLayout);
            connection.Close();
            i++;

        }
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it's too late to answer the question, but hopefully this can help others who face the same problem in the future.

Here is my code:

```
private void AddProductsToTabbedPanel()
    {
        int i = 1;

        foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sdaProductType = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Description FROM TblProducts WHERE ProductType =" + i.ToString(), con);

            FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sdaProductType.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                b.Text = dr["Description"].ToString();
                flp.Controls.Add(b);
            }

            tp.Controls.Add(flp);
            i++;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```