# How to filter displayed products according to their category in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Okay. After several hours of thinking I decided to ask my question again since I couldn't make it work even though I had some guidance from answers in my previous question. [Here's my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247117/how-to-filter-displayed-products-according-to-the-its-producttype-in-tabcontrol)

Now I'm creating a point of sale system and I want display products dynamically in my database as buttons on TabControl - TabPages according to their ProductType. But the problem is, I could get those products to TabPags as buttons but the I can't sort them out to each TabPage according to their ProductType as same list of products display on every TabPage as below.

[image]

And this my database.

[image]

```
private void CreateTabPages() // Create Tab Pages for each ProductType
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT ProductType, Description FROM TblProductType", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(dr["ProductType"].ToString(),dr["Description"].ToString());
            }

            con.Close();   
        }


    private void AddProductsToTabbedPanel() // Add Products to Tab Pages
{

    foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM TblProduct", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            b.Text = dr["Description"].ToString(); 
            flp.Controls.Add(b);
        }

        tp.Controls.Add(flp);
        con.Close();
    }


}
```

I would really appreciate any feedback you could give me on this.

Comment: Of course it's a duplicate, just read the description, he wrote he decided to ask his question again.

Comment: @pinckerman That comment appears automatically when someone votes to close a question due to it being a duplicate. I just edited the comment to remove the first word ("possible"). Duplicate questions in SO are frowned upon.

Comment: @Renan- What's wrong with you? Could you just answer my question without stating the obvious.

Comment: @Renan sorry, I didn't know this feature.

Comment: Okay guys. Could you just stop your cat fight for a moment and tell me how to attract more members to my previous question. The only way I know is, to ask it again as I don't have bounty to offer.

Comment: I'll be honest and straight to the point with you: there are so many wrong things with your app design that you seriously need a few basic courses on C# and software engineering. You should also switch to ASP.NET. It may seem more complex than Windows applications at first but it will make things better for you on the long run. It will also solve two problems you have there: you'll get a more sensible UI, and the fact that you'll have to rethink your UI will get you past what you think your problem is here.

Comment: Can you use WPF for this? Or is it just WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Yes, I know the OP's pictures show WinForms, but in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247117/how-to-filter-displayed-products-according-to-the-its-producttype-in-tabcontrol) the OP stated that they was following a tutorial on `YouTube`. I thought I'd provide another way that he could represent the same data using WPF.

You could use a `Model` to display each of your `DataTypes`, instead of handling the `Raw Data`; have a look at [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), something like Entity-Framework, NHibernate, etc.

Create a `Product` model to hold the data from the `Product` table.

```
public class Product {
    public int ProductID {get;set;}
    public int ProductType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Create a `Product Type` model to hold the data from the `Product Type` table.

```
public class ProductType {
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Create a `Window`/`UserControl` to hold your `TabControl`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ProductConverter x:Key="ProductConverter" />
    <local:ProductTypeConverter x:Key="ProductTypeConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyProducts, 
            Converter={StaticResource ProductConverter}}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ProductTypeConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ProductType"/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.MyProductTypes" 
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Width="150" Content="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Using a `ItemTemplate` and `ContentTemplate` will ensure that all your `Product` objects will have the same format and styling.

This is the converter that converts your entire list of `Products` into groups of `Products` based on the `Product Type` value.

```
public class ProductConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if(value as List<Product> != null) {
            return (value as List<Product>).GroupBy(a => new { a.ProductType });
        }

        return null;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the converter than converts `Product.ProductType` value into the `ProductType.Description`

```
public class ProductTypeConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if(values[0] != null && values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue &&
            values[1] != null && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) {
            string f= (values[1] as List<ProductType>)
                      .Where(a => a.ProductTypeID.Equals(values[0]))
                      .First().Description;
            return f;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Create [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) for using in displaying the `TabControl.Items`.

```
public List<Product> MyProducts { get; set; }
public List<ProductType> MyProductTypes { get; set; }
```

Afterwards, all you have to do is represent your `Raw Data` in a model format. (My SQL is a bit iffy)

```
    SqlCommand sqlCmdProducts = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TblProduct", myConnection);
SqlDataReader productReader = sqlCmdProducts.ExecuteReader();
while (productReader.Read()) {
    MyProductTypes.Add(new ProductType() {
    ProductTypeID = Int32.Parse(productReader["ProductType"].ToString()),
    Description = Int32.Parse(productReader["Description"].ToString()),
    };
}

SqlCommand sqlCmdProductType = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TblProductType", myConnection);
SqlDataReader productTypeReader = sqlCmdProductType.ExecuteReader();
while (productTypeReader.Read()) {
    MyProducts.Add(new Product() {
    ProductID = Int32.Parse(productTypeReader["ProductID"].ToString()),
    ProductType = Int32.Parse(productTypeReader["ProductType"].ToString()),
    Description = productTypeReader["Description"].ToString()),
    Price = double.Parse(productTypeReader["Price"].ToString()),
    };
}
```